# Unable to get page source of XML and do any operations on it using selenium webdriver

Tags: xml, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to automate a web application in Chrome browser and performing the following steps:

1. Open the application
2. Click on a link which opens a child browser window containing an XML from which I have to get some value.

Now, I'm successfully able to switch to the child window and maximize it using selenium but after that the webdriver just hangs without doing anything. I tried to get the PageSource manually and was successful.But there's an issue when I try to do it with Webdriver.Same issue while getting the page title also.I cannot provide the XML or screenprint due to security reasons. Any suggestions/help would be great.

Thanks,
Vishal S

Comment: What's this issue? "there's an issue when I try to do it with Webdriver.Same issue while getting the page title also"

Comment: I'm unable to get Page source of the XML or get values out of it and also unable to get the pagetitle of the child window in which the XML is open.

Comment: without knowing what is it that child window contains, I don't think anyone can answer this question

Comment: Why are you maximizing the window? Whether your approach works without maximization?

Comment: Just wanted to check if I'm able to switch to that child window

Comment: I tried both with and without maximizing.Both ways I'm unable to read the XML, get the page title and get page source using webdriver. Just checking if it has something do with the security feature of chrome?

Comment: We found a workaround for this.Thanks